# Get cursor position inside a rectangle

Tags: excel, position, coordinates, vba

How do I get the coordinates of the cursor position relative to a rectangle (the one I use to call the macro)?
Here what I got this far:

First: I use the function:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (Point As POINTAPI) As Long
Type POINTAPI
   X As Long
   Y As Long
End Type
```

to get the coordinates of the cursor on the screen. Those values are returned by:

```
Point.X 'pixels to the left of the screen
Point.Y 'pixels to the top of the screen
```

Second: I created a rectangle like this:

[image: a rectangle on a spreadsheet]

and set the following macro to it:

```
Sub SH03G13()
    Dim Point As POINTAPI: GetCursorPos Point
    Dim rectang As Shape: Set rectang = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("SH03G13BACK")
    Dim ABCISSA As Long: ABCISSA = Point.X - rectang.Left
    Dim ORDENAD As Long: ORDENAD = Point.Y - rectang.Top

    MsgBox ABCISSA & " " & ORDENAD

End Sub
```

On my mind, when I did this, I was positive I was getting the coordinates of the cursor inside the green rectangle. However, when I clicked on the black spot on the next image:

[image: a rectangle with a black spot on a spreadsheet]

the coordinates that my plan returned weren't the expected near 0 coordinates I thought:

[image: Output message box]

Then I realized that the `GetCursorPos` were returning the position of the cursor relative to the screen while the `rectang.Left` and `rectang.Top` commands on my script were returning the position of the rectangle relative to the spreadsheet. So, the lines `Point.X - rectang.Left` and `Point.X - rectang.Left` couldn't possibly be right.

Any ideas how I could get the correct coordinates? i.e How can I get the right coordinates near 0 by clicking on the black spot?
Any help will be very appreciated. And, as always, thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the shape? because I think when you add the shape you give the position by parameter, If that is the case you have to subtract that quantity from the cursor position.

Comment: I don't add the shape with a code. But, if I did, I surely have to use the same values I get with the `.Left` and `.Top` commands.

Comment: perhaps this can be of help: https://excel.tips.net/T003421_Determining_Mouse_Cursor_Coordinates_On_a_Graphic.html

Comment: Thank you @Luuklag. That's a great article. However, it can't be an ActiveX control. It has to be an image from excel automatic shapes database (because I have to set it transparent).

Comment: Is there a reason the shape does not allign with the cells, or is that possible? That would greatly simplify things I think.

Comment: Yes @Luuklag. The shape is align with the cells. In fact, they are align by a previous macro. So the shape is exactly align with a range of cells.

Comment: @Luuklag, I think you might gave me an answer without big effort. I could use the cells alignment to get what I want. I will approach this idea   and maybe I'll get rid of this headache.

Comment: _However, it can't be an ActiveX control. It has to be an image from excel automatic shapes database (because I have to set it transparent)_  You can make ActiveX Image transparent and handle it's MouseMove event, but please consider explaining why exactly do you need mouse coordinates on invisible shape - maybe you will get a better answer.

Comment: Sorry @BrakNicku, but this issue involves a work related problem and I can't explicit the details on this matter. It really can't be an ActiveX control. However, after days of research and frustrated attempts, I think I figure it out and found the solution. I'll soon post it.

Comment: @Luuklag, I found the solution to this problem partially thanks to you (and your idea to use the cells alignment to get the coordinates I was looking for). Could you formally post this idea to an answer? After all, I think the bounty should't be wasted...

Comment: @Luuklag really? Thanks (I didn't even know I could do that)...

Comment: But it will go there by default when it is the most upvoted answer when everything expires

Comment: You can read up on how this works: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 5):

As I told, I got what I want after exploring an idea gived to me by @Luuklag (by aligning the rectangle with a range of cells).

First I put the next code on a different module (just for a well organized code matter):

```
Option Explicit
Type RECT
    Left As Long: Top As Long: Right As Long: Bottom As Long
End Type
Type POINTAPI
    X As Long: Y As Long
End Type
Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (Point As POINTAPI) As Long
Function ScreenDPI(bVert As Boolean) As Long
    Static lDPI&(1), lDC&
    If lDPI(0) = 0 Then
        lDC = GetDC(0)
        lDPI(0) = GetDeviceCaps(lDC, 88&)
        lDPI(1) = GetDeviceCaps(lDC, 90&)
        lDC = ReleaseDC(0, lDC)
    End If
    ScreenDPI = lDPI(Abs(bVert))
End Function
Function PTtoPX(Points As Single, bVert As Boolean) As Long
    PTtoPX = Points * ScreenDPI(bVert) / 72
End Function
Sub GetRangeRect(ByVal rng As Range, ByRef rc As RECT)
    Dim wnd As Window: Set wnd = rng.Parent.Parent.Windows(1)
    With rng
        rc.Left = PTtoPX(.Left * wnd.Zoom / 100, 0) + wnd.PointsToScreenPixelsX(0)
        rc.Top = PTtoPX(.Top * wnd.Zoom / 100, 1) + wnd.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)
        rc.Right = PTtoPX(.Width * wnd.Zoom / 100, 0) + rc.Left
        rc.Bottom = PTtoPX(.Height * wnd.Zoom / 100, 1) + rc.Top
    End With
End Sub
```

After this, I set the rectangle with the next macro:

```
Sub SH03G13()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim AreaRng As Range: Set AreaRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(13, 10))
        Dim rectang As Shape: Set rectang = .Shapes("SH03G13BACK")
            rectang.Height = AreaRng.Height
            rectang.Width = AreaRng.Width
            rectang.Top = AreaRng.Top
            rectang.Left = AreaRng.Left
            DoEvents
        Dim Point As POINTAPI: GetCursorPos Point
        Dim rc As RECT: Call GetRangeRect(.Cells(2, 2), rc)
        Dim ABCISSA As Long: ABCISSA = Point.X - rc.Left
        Dim ORDENAD As Long: ORDENAD = Point.Y - rc.Top
    End With

    MsgBox "x: " & ABCISSA & ", y: " & ORDENAD

End Sub
```

The previous macro places and adjusts the rectangle `SH03G13BACK` to the `.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(13, 10)` range. Once this is done, the `Point.X - rc.Left` and `Point.Y - rc.Top` commands gave me the exact coordinates inside the rectangle (and relative to it), regardless the maximized/minimized state of the excel window, the zoom value, the size/contents of the excel command ribbon or the size/resolution of the screen itself. It's perfect:

[image: Coordinates of the black spot]

I realize this is a little cheating (I know that the `GetRangeRect` subroutine gives the coordinates relative to the `.Cells(2, 2)` position. However, for this matter, the trick works like a charm.

Comment: This still won't work with some user preference settings I mentioned like Split panes or frozen panes, your coordinates will be relative to the pane, just for example, you can never assume users will use your program like you want them to. But, provided it's not meant to be production ready code, it's a great start and good workaround

Comment: Actually, it does. The sheet in question doesn't have split or frozen panes and it's protected. The users of the file will not be able to edit those. So, on this specific case, this solution will work (in fact it's been working for two days now without any problems).

Comment: Right, but I was just using that particular setting as an example, there are numerous more client side settings that will alter your results. But if it suits your needs that's all that matters.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to deal with that too... Honesty I didn't check it out.

Comment: Not sure, even if you protect your sheet like you mentioned above and only allow to `Edit Objects`, it doesn't stop users from using the Application options/settings at their own free will, protected sheets only limit interaction with the spreadsheet. Application settings like Split Pane aren't governed by Protected privileges. But I like the answer, it's a solid workaround. Good job.

Comment: use `shape.topleft` and `shape.bottomright` to obtain the shape's range

Comment: `ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 0` and `ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 0` can be controlled by the procedure that sets the shape coordinates, as well as most application settings.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is Points.X & Points.Y are not relative to the document or the clients individual monitor setup, forget about multi-monitor setups. For example, if the cursor pos = (1000,500) but the application isn't full screen, you have to take into account `Application.Left` / `Application.Top` values.

Even so, this isn't a true depiction of where your shape is. rectang.Left / rectang.Top are not relative to the spreadsheet as you mention, they are relative to the spreadsheet object, or window if you will. Meaning, if you were to move the rectangle all the way to the left and top of the spreadsheet it would be (0,0). As show below:

[image]

Now, lets say we remove the column headings as well as the formula bar from the ActiveWindow object, the coordinates maintain their position, as shown below:

[image]

Clearly they Application environment size has changed, not the rectang.Left position. With that being said, a cursor position of Application.Top + rectang.Top will never be a true representation of where the top of the rectangle is, unless you account for all these run-time circumstances.

Let's say you do take these into account, you do have access to some settings with the `ActiveWindow` object, like `Application.ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings`, and you do make sure you do your best to omit these concerns. You still have a bunch of user preferences to consider, i.e, displayed scrollbars to account for, tabs, the actual ribbon, which may or may not be the same size across clients, minimized or maximized, page layouts, what the current zoom level is alone will cause conflicts, and don't forget about content panes. Let's take, for example, the format shape window pane, moving it to the left of the application and resizing it to an obnoxious width defined by a user:

[image]

The coordinates still maintain their relative position, which will not correlate to the cursor position regardless of what properties you have access to, because it will always depend on the user's environment settings.

At this time, my answer would be to say there is no reasonable 'out-of-the-box' method to accomplish this, also for another simple reason that Shape Objects in Excel do not have event handlers for things like onclick or otherwise, in addition to `Worksheet.SelectionChange` does not fire for selection of Shapes afaik. You could potentially find a "hacky" way by running a loop to continually check for current selection etc, but naturally this is not desired for performance reasons.

As a built in means of accomplishing this, until there are event handlers added for Shape Objects, your best bet might be to port this over to a COM AddIn or populate some kind of VBA Windows Form in the Worksheet where you have more control over client positions, do all your shape manipulation in the form, then add the final product to the spreadsheet when the user is done.

Comment: I used a cells alignment idea to solve this issue. Soon I'll post it as an answer. Thanks, however, for you explanation. Is quite thorough...

Answer (score 1):

**NEW EDITED VERSION**

Take a look at the following code. The core idea is to use [RangeFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/window-rangefrompoint-method-excel), that returns the Shape or Range object that is positioned at the specified pair of screen coordinates.

There logical steps are:
**1)** get the clicking position and screen dimensions (in pixels).
**2)** get the first two cells in the visible range that belongs to different row/column, and get their 'excel' position as well as their pixel position.
**3)** Calculate the relation between 'Excel units' and pixels.
**4)** scan all shapes in worksheet, take their excel position and calculate their pixel position.

Although a little verbose (not too long, if you delete all lines for writing variables to sheet), I think the code is rather straight, without the need for positioning shapes along cells or checking zoom or similar. You can have many shapes in the sheet, and assign the code to all of them.

The only requirement is that the four cell on the top-left corner of the visible window must not be covered by a shape.

The below code is writing the different variables in the sheet, just for clarity.

```
Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByRef lpPoint As POINT) As Long

Private Type POINT
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Public Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal index As Long) As Long
Public Const SM_CXSCREEN = 0
Public Const SM_CYSCREEN = 1

Sub GetPixelsFromImageBorder()
    Dim pLocation As POINT
    Dim objShape As Object
    Dim ScreenWidth As Integer
    Dim ScreenHeight As Integer
    Dim xPix As Integer, yPix As Integer
    Dim Cell_1_X As Double, Cell_1_Y As Double
    Dim Cell_2_X As Double, Cell_2_Y As Double
    Dim Cell_1_Row As Integer, Cell_1_Col As Integer
    Dim Cell_2_Row As Integer, Cell_2_Col As Integer
    Dim Cell_1_X_Pix As Double, Cell_1_Y_Pix As Double
    Dim Cell_2_X_Pix As Double, Cell_2_Y_Pix As Double
    Dim Y0 As Double, X0 As Double
    Dim SlopeX As Double, SlopeY As Double
    Dim flg1 As Boolean, flg2 As Boolean, flg3 As Boolean
    Dim WhichWS As Worksheet
    Dim w As Window, r As Range, cll As Range
    Dim Shp As Shape

    Call GetCursorPos(pLocation)

    Set WhichWS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    WhichWS.Range("A1:H20").ClearContents

    ScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
    ScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)

    ClickX = pLocation.x
    ClickY = pLocation.y

    WhichWS.Cells(3, 1) = "Variable"
    WhichWS.Cells(3, 1).Font.Bold = True
    WhichWS.Cells(3, 2) = "X"
    WhichWS.Cells(3, 2).Font.Bold = True
    WhichWS.Cells(3, 3) = "Y"
    WhichWS.Cells(3, 3).Font.Bold = True

    WhichWS.Cells(4, 1) = "Screen (in pixels): "
    WhichWS.Cells(4, 2) = ScreenWidth
    WhichWS.Cells(4, 3) = ScreenHeight

    WhichWS.Cells(5, 1) = "Mouse clicked on (in pixels): "
    WhichWS.Cells(5, 2) = ClickX
    WhichWS.Cells(5, 3) = ClickY

    Set w = ActiveWindow
    Set r = w.VisibleRange
    i = 1
    For Each cll In r.Cells
        If i = 1 Then
            'get top and right pos (in excel units) of first cell in visible range
            'also get row and column of that cell
            Cell_1_Y = cll.Top
            Cell_1_X = cll.Left
            Cell_1_Row = cll.Row
            Cell_1_Col = cll.Column
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf cll.Row > Cell_1_Row And cll.Column > Cell_1_Col Then
            'get top and right pos (in excel units) of second cell in visible range
            'also get row and column of that cell
            Cell_2_Y = cll.Top
            Cell_2_X = cll.Left
            Cell_2_Row = cll.Row
            Cell_2_Col = cll.Column
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    On Error Resume Next
    flg1 = False
    flg2 = False
    flg3 = False
    For yPix = 1 To ScreenHeight
        For xPix = 1 To ScreenWidth
            Set objShape = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(xPix, yPix)
            If Not objShape Is Nothing Then
                If TypeName(objShape) = "Range" Then
                    If objShape.Column = Cell_1_Col And objShape.Row = Cell_1_Row Then
                        'get top and right pos (in pix) of first cell in visible range
                        If flg2 = False Then
                            Cell_1_X_Pix = xPix
                            Cell_1_Y_Pix = yPix
                            flg2 = True
                        End If
                    ElseIf objShape.Column = Cell_2_Col And objShape.Row = Cell_2_Row Then
                        'get top and right pos (in pix) of second cell in visible range
                        If flg3 = False Then
                            Cell_2_X_Pix = xPix
                            Cell_2_Y_Pix = yPix
                            flg3 = True
                            flg1 = True 'exit of outer loop
                            Exit For 'exit inner loop (this)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If flg1 = True Then Exit For
    Next

    'Calculate the relation between pixels and 'excel position'

    SlopeY = (Cell_2_Y_Pix - Cell_1_Y_Pix) / (Cell_2_Y - Cell_1_Y)
    Y0 = Cell_1_Y_Pix - SlopeY * Cell_1_Y

    SlopeX = (Cell_2_X_Pix - Cell_1_X_Pix) / (Cell_2_X - Cell_1_X)
    X0 = Cell_1_X_Pix - SlopeX * Cell_1_X

    'print some variables in sheet

    WhichWS.Cells(6, 1) = "Variable"
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 1).Font.Bold = True
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 2) = "X Pos (excel units)"
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 2).Font.Bold = True
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 3) = "Y Pos (excel units)"
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 3).Font.Bold = True
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 4) = "X Pos (pixels)"
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 4).Font.Bold = True
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 5) = "Y Pos (pixels)"
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 5).Font.Bold = True
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 6) = "X Dist. from click (pixels)"
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 6).Font.Bold = True
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 7) = "Y Dist. from click (pixels)"
    WhichWS.Cells(6, 7).Font.Bold = True


    i = 7
    For Each Shp In WhichWS.Shapes
        WhichWS.Cells(i, 1) = Shp.Name
        WhichWS.Cells(i, 2) = Shp.Left
        WhichWS.Cells(i, 3) = Shp.Top

        PosInPixX = X0 + Shp.Left * SlopeX
        PosInPixY = Y0 + Shp.Top * SlopeY
        DistFromClickX = ClickX - PosInPixX
        DistFromClickY = ClickY - PosInPixY

        WhichWS.Cells(i, 4) = Round(PosInPixX, 2)
        WhichWS.Cells(i, 5) = Round(PosInPixY, 2)
        WhichWS.Cells(i, 6) = DistFromClickX
        WhichWS.Cells(i, 7) = DistFromClickY
        i = i + 1
    Next Shp

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you handle `Rectángulo1_Click`? The shape is a autoshape from excel images db, not an ActiveX control...

Comment: Right click over image--> assign macro. And please change the name of the sub: I use a spanish versions of excel, and other version might have problems with accents. I already change the post.

Comment: Ah. ok... I thought it was a sub with an event handler. I will try your solution.

Comment: Sorry... This makes my excel shut down... Without recovery option. Man!

Comment: I wonder if this code can be sped up by limiting the area that is stepped through on a pixel by pixel basis. If you can narrow down somewhat into where the shape is located, that could save a ton of computing.

Comment: mmmhh... I don't have that problem. Although it might take a while, particularly if the image is in the bottom-right corner (scan start at upper-left...).

Comment: How about find the pixel at which Cell A1 starts, and determine the ratio between excel units and pixels. Then you could calculate the pixel where the shape is.

Comment: @Luuklag you can adjust the precision adding `step` to for loops

Comment: That would be an interesting one @CMArg, if you take step 25 for example, and then once found work backwards at step 1 to when you are no longer in the shape.

Comment: Might be. Anyway it becomes a optimization problem, but the core idea remains the same.  Regarding the ratio you mention, I do not properly understand 'excel units'...

Comment: You calculate these  `WhatWS.Cells(5, 1) = "Shape Pos (in 'excel units'): "
    WhatWS.Cells(5, 2) = Xrect
    WhatWS.Cells(5, 3) = Yrect` So if you then know how this translates into pixels, and you know the position in pixels of the upper left corner of CellA1 ((0,0) in excel units). You can calculate the position of the shape, without looping all the way to the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

This solution generates the Shape Screen coordinates, following this steps:

1. Ensures the shape worksheet is active *(application.WindowState could be either xlNormal or xlMaximized)*
2. Set the shape object
3. Sets the shape range screen coordinates
4. Sets the shape screen coordinates by scanning shape range screen coordinates

*This solutions does not need the shape to be aligned to the cells.*

Tested successfully for the following situations:

a)  Excel window in laptop screen, WindowState =xlNormal

b)  Excel window in laptop screen, WindowState =xlMaximized

c)  Excel window in alternate screen, WindowState =xlNormal

d)  Excel window in alternate screen, WindowState =xlMaximized

These are the procedures:

```
Option Explicit

Public Type RgCrds
    Top As Long
    Left As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
    End Type

Public Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long


Public Function Shape_ƒCoordinates_Get(uSpCrds As RgCrds, sp As Shape) As Boolean
Dim wd As Window, rg As Range, oj As Object
Dim uSpOutput As RgCrds, uRgCrds As RgCrds
Dim lX As Long, lY As Long
Dim blX As Boolean, blY As Boolean
Dim b As Byte
On Error GoTo Exit_Err

    Rem Set Shape Worksheet Window
    sp.TopLeftCell.Worksheet.Activate
    Set wd = ActiveWindow

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Rem Set Shape Range
    Set rg = Range(sp.TopLeftCell, sp.BottomRightCell)

    Rem Get Shape Range Coordinates
    Call Range_ScreenCoordinates_Get(uRgCrds, rg)

    Rem Set Shape Coordinates Limites
    With uSpOutput
        .Top = uRgCrds.Bottom
        .Left = uRgCrds.Right
        .Right = uRgCrds.Left
        .Bottom = uRgCrds.Top
    End With

    Rem Scan Shape Range to Get Shape Coordinates - [TopLeft Corner]
    blX = False: blY = False
    For lX = uRgCrds.Left To uRgCrds.Right
        For lY = uRgCrds.Top To uRgCrds.Bottom
            Set oj = wd.RangeFromPoint(lX, lY)
            If TypeName(oj) <> "Range" Then
                If oj.ShapeRange.Type = sp.Type And oj.Name = sp.Name Then
                    Shape_ƒCoordinates_Get = True
                    With uSpOutput
                        If lY < .Top Then .Top = lY Else blX = True
                        If lX < .Left Then .Left = lX Else blY = True
                        If blX And blY Then Exit For

    End With: End If: End If: Next: Next

    Rem Scan Shape Range to Get Shape Coordinates [BottomRight Corner]
    blX = False: blY = False
    For lX = uRgCrds.Right To uRgCrds.Left Step -1
        For lY = uRgCrds.Bottom To uRgCrds.Top Step -1
            Set oj = wd.RangeFromPoint(lX, lY)
            If TypeName(oj) <> "Range" Then
                If oj.ShapeRange.Type = sp.Type And oj.Name = sp.Name Then
                    Shape_ƒCoordinates_Get = True
                    With uSpOutput
                        If lX > .Right Then .Right = lX Else: blX = True
                        If lY > .Bottom Then .Bottom = lY Else: blY = True
                        If blX And blY Then Exit For

    End With: End If: End If: Next: Next

    Rem Coordinates Fine-Tuning
    ' The RangeFromPoint Method recognizes the Shapes,
    ' as soon as any part of the cursor is over the shape,
    ' therefore some fine-tuning is required in order
    ' to place the entire mouse inside the Shape's body
    b = 15  'change as required
    With uSpOutput
        .Top = .Top + b
        .Left = .Left + b
        .Right = .Right - b
        .Bottom = .Bottom - b
    End With

    Rem Set Results
    uSpCrds = uSpOutput
    Shape_ƒCoordinates_Get = True

Exit_Err:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Function

Public Sub Range_ScreenCoordinates_Get(uOutput As RgCrds, ByVal rg As Range)
Dim wd As Window
    With rg

        Rem Activate range's worksheet window
        .Worksheet.Activate
        Application.Goto .Worksheet.Cells(1), 1
        Set wd = ActiveWindow

        Rem Set Range Screen Coordinates
        uOutput.Top = Points_ƒToPixels(.Top * wd.Zoom / 100, 1) + wd.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)
        uOutput.Left = Points_ƒToPixels(.Left * wd.Zoom / 100, 0) + wd.PointsToScreenPixelsX(0)
        uOutput.Right = Points_ƒToPixels(.Width * wd.Zoom / 100, 0) + uOutput.Left
        uOutput.Bottom = Points_ƒToPixels(.Height * wd.Zoom / 100, 1) + uOutput.Top

    End With

    End Sub

Private Function Points_ƒToPixels(sgPoints As Single, blVert As Boolean) As Long
    Points_ƒToPixels = sgPoints * Screen_ƒDPI(blVert) / 72
    End Function

Private Function Screen_ƒDPI(blVert As Boolean) As Long
Static lDPI(0 To 1) As Long, lDC As Long
    If lDPI(0) = 0 Then
        lDC = GetDC(0)
        lDPI(0) = GetDeviceCaps(lDC, 88&)
        lDPI(1) = GetDeviceCaps(lDC, 90&)
        lDC = ReleaseDC(0, lDC)
    End If
    Screen_ƒDPI = lDPI(Abs(blVert))
    End Function
```

Copy the procedures above in a standard module then copy this procedure in a separated module

```
Option Explicit    

Sub Shape_Coordinates_Get_TEST()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sp As Shape
Dim uSpCrds As RgCrds

    Rem Set Target Worksheet Active Window
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SO_Q50293831")  'replace as required
    With ws
        .Activate
        Set sp = .Shapes("SH03G13BACK")
    End With

    Rem Get Shape Coordinates
    If Not (Shape_ƒCoordinates_Get(uSpCrds, sp)) Then Exit Sub  'might want to add a message

    Rem Apply Shape Coordinates
    With uSpCrds
        SetCursorPos .Left, .Top: Stop         ' Mouse is now at the Shape's TopLeft corner
        SetCursorPos .Left, .Bottom: Stop      ' Mouse is now at the Shape's LeftBottom corner
        SetCursorPos .Right, .Top: Stop        ' Mouse is now at the Shape's RightTop corner
        SetCursorPos .Right, .Bottom: Stop     ' Mouse is now at the Shape's BottomRigh corner
    End With

    End Sub
```

For additional information about the resources used visit these pages:

[GetDeviceCaps function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877(v=vs.85).aspx)

[GetDC function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871(v=vs.85).aspx)

[ReleaseDC function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162920(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Visual Basic Procedure to Get/Set Cursor Position](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/152969/visual-basic-procedure-to-get-set-cursor-position)

Comment: This solution includes an efficient scan of the shape range.

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there with your code. However Excel App has ribbon that takes some space. In this case, `ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(0)` and `ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)` will return your worksheet starting pixels relative to the screen.

Now the `(mousePos) - (worksheet position) - (left and top of the shapeIn Pixel)` will give you mouse position relative to your shape.

Try this code:

```
Public Function SH03G13()
    Dim point As POINTAPI: GetCursorPos point
    Dim rectang As Shape: Set rectang = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("SH03G13BACK")

    Debug.Print "Mouse pointer relative to screen:", point.X, point.Y
    Debug.Print "Mouse pointer relative to app:", (point.X - ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(0)), (point.Y - ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0))
    Debug.Print "Mouse pointer relative to shape:", ((point.X - ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(0)) - PointToPixel(rectang.Left)), ((point.Y - ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)) - PointToPixel(rectang.Top))
    Dim ABCISSA As Long: ABCISSA = point.X - rectang.Left
    Dim ORDENAD As Long: ORDENAD = point.Y - rectang.Top

'Debug.Print ABCISSA & " " & ORDENAD



End Function

Public Function PointToPixel(point As Double) As Double
'Converts points to pixel
    If point > 0 Then PointToPixel = Round((1.33333333333333 * point), 2) Else PointToPixel = 0
End Function
```

results in your immediate window will be:

```
Mouse pointer relative to screen:          410           356 
Mouse pointer relative to app:             384           313 
Mouse pointer relative to shape:           0             0
```

**Note**: You might get -1 coordinates, that's because the on click event fires even if you click slightly away from the shape. You can catch this easily in your function.